# CloudFlare, free SSL and subdomains with www

Tags: ssl, subdomain, redirect, cloudflare

I have a `somedomain.com` on CloudFlare with free SSL. And I have subdomains: eg. `pl.somedomain.com`.

SSL works on:

- https://somedomain.com
- https://www.somedomain.com
- https://en.somedomain.com
- https://pl.somedomain.com

but not works on:

```
https://www.pl.somedomain.com
https://www.fr.somedomain.com
```

So I am looking for some solution these subdomains work.

`http://www.fr.somedomain.com` redirects to `https://www.fr.somedomain.com`
and I have error.

Is any solution using .htaccess or Page Rules to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of SSL in general. No browsers support multi-level wildcard certificates and no trusted CA will issue them (in SSL world www. is also counted as sub-domain). The free universal SSL certificate provided by Cloudflare supports the root and wildcard domain on a shared certificate. For more levels, dedicated certificates or custom host names a different certificate is needed.

If you are looking to secure multiple wildcard domains, but want to keep them all under one certificate, than you should go for the Multi-Domain Wildcard SSL certificates.

Multi-Domain Wildcard Certificates can secure both fully-qualified domain names and wildcard domains within their SAN entries. The coverage for a Multi-Domain wildcard certificate would look like this:

Common Name: domain.com

```
SAN 1: *.website.org
SAN 2: www.example.net
SAN 3: *.mail.site.com
SAN 4: address.edu
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can apply page rules to 2 level deep domain names, but give the following a try (based on [tutorial from CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-PageRules-)):

Redirect from pattern:

```
https://www.*.somedomain.com/*
```

to:

```
https://$1.somedomain.com/$2
```

Answer (score -1):

On the CloudFlare website, they mentioned redirecting by using the redirect option in their control panel.
1. Go to Control panel and select page rules.
2. On page rule section add new URL and make sure to select forwarding option enabled.
3. Enter the destination URL and select the forwarding type.
For example, 
Example forwarding to Google+:
Imagine you have a Google+ profile and you want to make it easy for anyone coming to get to simply by going to a URL like:

```
 *www.example.com/+

 *example.com/+
```

Give that a try, and if you are still getting this issue afterward, I advise checking this [list](https://www.blogmytech.com/how-to/free-ssl-certificate-for-website) of other SSL providers that is free.

Comment: Hi, please clarify with an example.